# Mathematical confusion in electric field definition

Tags: electrostatics, potential, vector-fields, mathematics

I have seen the following in some electromagnetism notes:
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf r)=\cfrac{1}{4πε_0}\int_V\cfrac{ρ(\mathbf r')\hat R}{R^2} \;d V'=
-\cfrac{1}{4πε_0}\int_V ρ(\mathbf r')\nabla \biggl(\cfrac{1}{R}\biggr) \;d V' \implies
$$
$$
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf r)=-\cfrac{1}{4πε_0}\nabla \Biggl( \int_V \cfrac{ρ(\mathbf r')}{R} \;d V' \biggr) \tag1
$$
where $\mathbf r$ is the field point, $\mathbf r'$ the source point and $\mathbf {R = r - r' } \quad(2)$

I cannot understand why in $(1)$ we can swap the integral and the del operator, since $r'$ is the integration variable and $R$ is a function of $r'$, beacuse of $(2)$. Can anyone please explain that?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't matter that $R$ is also a function of $r'$: the point is that the derivative is only with respect to $r$. $R$ being a function of $r'$ means that you cannot take *it* out of the integral, but no one is doing that!

This is what's known as the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), which basically just says that if $f(x,y)$ is a function with continuous derivatives, then

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_a^b f(x,y)\, dy = \int_a^b \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\, dy.$$

This is basically the same as in your question, just with a bit of a different notation. Notice that it doesn't matter what $f$ is; it can be any function of *both* variables. In a way, it's another way of stating Fubini's theorem that the order of variables doesn't matter in an integral.

Comment: Minor comment but may be important to some people.  Leibniz Integral Rule applies when limits of integration are functions of $x$.  Otherwise, taking the derivative of an integral with constant limits of integration always yields zero as you are taking the derivative of a constant.

Comment: @K7PEH the rule is still useful when the limits are constant; the integral is not a constant because the function being integrated depends on $x$.

Comment: it depends on how you view the integral (the one to the left of the equal sign).  If the integral truly has constant limits of integration than the derivative ALWAYS produces zero.  Also, you say the Integral is not constant because of the function being integrated.  What you mean to say is that the function is not a constant which is true.  But, an integral of such a function that has constant limits of integration is a constant -- a mere number.

Comment: @K7PEH I think you're confused. You're integrating with respect to $y$, but $f$ is also a function of $x$. The value of the whole integral, even with constant limits, depends on $x$, so you can take the derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: You are so right, I am indeed confused.  For some bizarre reason I didn't even take notice of $f(x,y)$ but merely thinking $f(x)dx$ at the beginning.  My fault.  You can properly ignore everything I said.

Comment: The situation I was describing with the constant limits of integration is one of the hardened memories I have.  About 50+ years ago, I took the Math GRE, and I missed a question which was to evaluate the the derivative of an integral with constant limits.  The answer was zero but I went ahead and moved the derivative into the function being integrated which by the way was one of the multiple choice answers in addition to zero being the correct answer.